# Apache Httpd in front of Tomcat for faster SSL processing?

Tags: tomcat, apache2

Does placing Apache httpd in front of Tomcat facilitate faster SSL processing?  Does the overall throughput go up or down when using both servers?

Answer (score 0):

Installing Apache to an other machine will increase the latency (the request has to go through one more machine) and the throughput (you have more cpu) too. [Apache JServ Protocol (AJP)](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy_ajp.html) ([AJP on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_JServ_Protocol)) is useful to link the Apache to the Tomcat and to reduce the increased latency:

> The AJP13 protocol is packet-oriented. A binary format was presumably
>   chosen over the more readable plain text for reasons of performance.
>   The web server communicates with the servlet container over TCP
>   connections. To cut down on the expensive process of socket creation,
>   the web server will attempt to maintain persistent TCP connections to
>   the servlet container, and to reuse a connection for multiple
>   request/response cycles.

(If you install them on the same machine... to be honest, I've never do that but I wouldn't think that there is a big difference in their SSL performance. Anyway, if it's important you should measure it. Don't miss [the FAQ in the Tomcat Wiki](http://wiki.apache.org/tomcat/FAQ/Connectors).)